# Sub-struct with dependent fields

Tags: matlab, oop, data-structures

In Matlab, I would like a data structure that looks like so:

```
DataStruct
   .model
     .Q
     .Qchol
      .
      .
   .system
      .
      .
```

The structure may well be a class, although I don't really need all the other functionality that goes with oop.

But I require

- If `Q` is assigned something, then automatically `Qchol = cholcov(Q)`.
- If `Qchol` is assigned something, then automatically `Q = Qchol' * Qchol`.
- Meanwhile, both `Q` and `Qchol` are stored for fast read-access
- And `Q` and `Qchol` are writable through simple assignment, e.g.: `DS1.mod.Q = value`

I know I can make `model` a class, and have set/get methods for Q and Qchol. However, this really seems like an overkill for just two matrices (plus maybe some more fields). Also Matlab *warns* me that I should not access other properties during in a set method.

So: What is the best way to have such data structures, preferably without warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want assignment (`DS1.mod.Q = value`) to have side-effects, which inevitably implies a setter, and hence a class. You should either drop this requirement, or write a class.

If you wish to avoid definition of properties in the class declaration, you could use [Dynamic Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/dynamic-properties--adding-properties-to-an-instance.html), which allows you to add properties at runtime (although with some telltale syntax `addprop()`).

**EDIT**

Patric, the problem goes deeper then just M-lint. Consider the following class:

```
classdef cantInstantiateMe < handle
    properties
        x
        minus_x
    end
    methods
        function obj = cantInstantiateMe(x)
            obj.x = x;   % <-- this calls set.x(), which calls set.minus_x(), which calls set.x(), ...
            obj.minus_x = -x;
        end

        function set.x(obj, value)
            obj.x = value;
            obj.minus_x = -value; % <-- this gives an M-Lint warning
        end

        function set.minus_x(obj, value)
            obj.minus_x = value;
            obj.x = -value;                
        end

    end
end
```

This class cannot be instantiated, because each setter calls the other setter (this is not Matlab-specific). Trying to instantiate on my machine gives:

> ??? Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
>   to change the limit.  Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can
>   crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

At this point I think you have two options:

- Make either `Q` or `Qchol` a [dependent property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-access-methods.html#bsxanmy). This will come at the cost of re-calculating the dependent property each time you read-access it.
- Use some private shadow properties e.g. `shadow_Q` and `shadow_Qchol` which will be set when the setter for the public property is called, and returned when their getter is called. Similar to:

  ```
   function set.x(obj, value)
          obj.shadow_x = value;
          obj.shadow_minus_x = -value;
   end

   function value = get.x(obj)
        value = obj.shadow_x;
   end
  ```

  Note the I did not test this properly, so I don't know all implications in Matlab. In other languages I'm familiar with, this should work fine.
- Regarding the warning - my approach is that it is safe to disable the warning, as long as you **really** know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the useful perspective on my issue, which makes your conclusion all the more obvious. What is your opinion on the warnings Matlab gives me? Surely such side-effects (affecting another property) must be a common wish? Surely there's a good way of doing it?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive edit. I in fact already tried your the non-instantiable example above. My approach was going to be adding an internal switch to tell the setter not to set the other one (coz it's already being set). But using your approach gives no mlint warnings, so it is probably cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [@bavaza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18420789/97160), one way to implement this is to use a dependent property with corresponding shadow private properties.

Below is the code implementing the inner data structure (inspired by [this post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/03/26/considering-performance-in-object-oriented-matlab-code/#8)). You need to use composition to make an instance of this class a property of the outer object:

```
classdef Model < handle
    properties (Dependent)
        Q
        Qchol
    end
    properties (Access = private)
        Q_
        Qchol_
    end

    methods
        function obj = Model()
        end

        function val = get.Q(obj)
            val = obj.Q_;
        end
        function val = get.Qchol(obj)
            val = obj.Qchol_;
        end

        function set.Q(obj, val)
            obj.Q_ = val;
            obj.Qchol_ = cholcov(val);
        end
        function set.Qchol(obj, val)
            obj.Qchol_ = val;
            obj.Q_ = val'*val;
        end
    end
end
```

Setting one value using the exposed dependent properties affects both underlying variables:

```
>> m = Model
m = 
  Model with properties:

        Q: []
    Qchol: []

>> m.Qchol = rand(3)
m = 
  Model with properties:

        Q: [3x3 double]
    Qchol: [3x3 double]
```

Comment: I'm glad to see this has no weird side-effect in Matlab. Added to my cookbook :)

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed the solution I have employed. I have yet to try out the composition, but I assume it will work fine.